# NavBar Item in Footer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have one problem need help.

My jquery mobile page, if I put the Navbar content static into the page:

```
<div data-role="footer">        
    <div id='footerButton' data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /navbar -->
</div><!-- /footer -->
```

The navbar button display Horizontally button nicely and automatically equal the width of each button.

But if I leave the Navbar DIV empty and dynamically insert the UL and LI:

```
$('#userMainPage').on('pagebeforecreate', function() {
    $('#footerButton').html('<ul><li><a href="#">One</a></li><li><a href="#">Two</a></li><li><a href="#">Three</a></li></ul>');
});
```

With the above code, the Item will not listed as Horizontal. It will became Vertical li without button styling.

May I know what is wrong with my code to insert the content dynamically? Please advice, thank you.

Comment: jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js

Comment: Append a fresh navbar `$(document).on('pagecreate', '#userMainPage', function () { $('.ui-footer').html($("<div id='footerButton' data-role='navbar'><ul><li><a href='#'>One</a></li><li><a href='#'>Two</a></li><li><a href='#'>Three</a></li></ul></div>").navbar());
});` http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/BfmZ3/

Comment: Ok I'll try. FYI, my footer is external static footer. Hope it doesn't have any conflict. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you're still in doubt, add more details and when you want to update navbar. Anyway, adding a fresh one is better, you won't face any conflicts whatsoever.

Comment: Hi @Omar, may I know what is wrong with my code? I wish to know what I've done wrong so in future I can avoid the same error. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @Omar, I success create the navbar work as expected using your recommended code. Thanks.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. I'm adding an answer with more explanation :)

Comment: @Omar, if you don't mind, please explain the usage of the .navbar() at the end of the code too. I try to search and try to understand why it's there. But no luck, didn't find anything explain that.

I'm very new to javascript. Just learning. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pagebeforecreate` event doesn't emit on *page*, it emits on *document*. Thus, you can't bind it to a specific page.

```
 /* has no effect on #pageID */
$("#pageID").on("pagebeforecreate", function (event)
$(document).on("pagebeforecreate", "#pageID", function (event)

/* to know which page is going to be created */
$(document).on("pagebeforecreate", function (event) {
  console.log(event.target);
});

/* this works, but you'll need to enhance dynamically added elements manually */
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#pageID", function (event) {
  /* do something */
  $("footer").append( $("<div data-role='navbar'></div>").navbar() );
});
```

In light of the above, if you want to perform something on `pagebeforecreate` event based on *page* that is being created:

```
$(document).on("pagebeforecreate", function (event) {
  var page = event.target.id;
  if(page == "pageID") {
    /* do something */
  }
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/LfA4E/)**

---

However, since `pagecreate` and `pagebeforecreate` fires ONCE per page, if you want to change *Navbar* every time a *specific* page is shown, you need to utilize *pageContainer* events, e.g. `pagecontainershow`. Those events don't emit on a *specific* page as well, so you need to retrieve *ActivePage*'s id.

Note that you will also need to inject "fresh/new" *Navbar* since this widget has no *refresh* methods.

```
$(document).on('pagecontainershow', function (event) {
  /* retrieve ID of active page */
  var page = $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("getActivePage")[0].id;
  if (page == "page1") {
    $('[data-role=footer]').html($("<div id='footerButton' data-role='navbar'><ul><li><a href='#'>One</a></li><li><a href='#'>Two</a></li><li><a href='#'>Three</a></li></ul></div>").navbar());
  } else {
    $('[data-role=footer]').html($("<div id='footerButton' data-role='navbar'><ul><li><a href='#'>Four</a></li><li><a href='#'>Five</a></li><li><a href='#'>Six</a></li></ul></div>").navbar());
  }
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/bNM37/)**

---

### Enhancement / manual initialization of Widget:

`.navbar()` is *enhancement* method of `data-role="navbar"` when it is injected dynamically. Static elements, e.g. *Navbar*, are auto-initialized when jQM framework is first initialized, or when they are retrieved via Ajax. However, when elements are dynamically injected, they need to be *initialized* manually, `.navbar()` is used for *Navbar* widget.

Comment: Sorry I type something wrong. Please ignore my previous comment. I'll remove it.

Now I'm adding in more things to make sure it all works well. Having some problem remove header and footer after user logout. Should I post new Question?

Thanks.

Comment: @user3053891 yes, post a new question with relevant details/code.